# Lazarus depurador invalido

Tags: delphi-7, lazarus, object-pascal, emulador, windows-ce

Instalei:
Lazarus 1.4.0/FPC 2.6.4 
Lazarus WinCE Cross Compile 
dentro da pasta C:\Lazarus

No Lazarus eu fiz a seguinte configuração:

1 - http://jbsolucoes.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/configandtarget.png

2 - http://jbsolucoes.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/lclwidgetsettype.png

3 - http://jbsolucoes.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/lclwidgetsettypeok.png

Criei um Form com botão só para testar, ao executar recebe o erro:

> The debugger "$(LazarusDir)\mingw\$(TargetCPU)-$(Targe...\gdb.exe does not exist or is not executable.

Tenho essas opções se eu colocar qualquer umas delas ele da erro.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14941609/debugger.png

Faltou eu instalar mais alguma coisa?

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso: Na tela Opçoes de IDE / Depurador / Geral:

Debugger_Startup_Options --> Altere "DisableLoadSymbolsForLibraries" para "True"

Veja detalhes em: [gdb.exe has stopped working](http://wiki.freepascal.org/GDB_Debugger_Tips)